# How to get user facebook id in a publish (server-side) Meteor

Tags: facebook, meteor, publish-subscribe

I have a facebook request dialog that for inviting friends to my app and of course i get a response with the invited users id's which then i store in a collection called "Groups" under users document: so it looks like this:

```
{ "creator" : "qzD5X33Jejq5BYRdZ", "name" : "Soccer", "emailAt" : 4, "date" : "10/31/2013", "friends" : [  "dude dude",  "another dude" ], "location" : "xxx", "rules" : "Soccer", "desc" : "Soccer", "users" : [  "100006794617787",  "100006832923859" ], "_id" : "ZMgzuy88EiSWF6xnS" }
```

and on my publish function i want only the creator and the users to have this group, i know that to access the user collection i need to use `this.user` and on the client i use `Meteor.user()`
so i tried this:

```
Meteor.publish("Teams",function(){
    return Groups.find({creator:this.userId},{users:this.user.services.facebook.id},{fields:{
        date:false,
        desc:false,
        rules:false,
        friends:false,
        location:false,
        emailAt:false
    }});
});
```

but as you can guess this is not working, any suggestions how to make it work?
note: im only using facebook login so this is very convenient to use the facebook id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can just call `this.user` (I think). You need to resolve it out so instead of `this.user` use `user` and resolve it out:

```
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
```

And the other is a small typo :):

```
return Groups.find({creator:this.userId, users:user.services.facebook.id}...
```

instead of

```
return Groups.find({creator:this.userId}, {users:this.user.services.facebook.id}...
```

Comment: tried it, not working, i think that i cant call the services.... inside the publish function, is it possible?

Comment: yeah i get an error : "Cannot read property 'services' of undefined
I2048-22:50:04.807(3)?     at Meteor.publish.Groups.find.creator [as _handler] (app/server/publishes/main.js:16:57)"

Comment: Did you also change the `this.user` to `user` as shown above, it needs to be resolved out to a valid user? The `services` property should be available anywhere on the server

Comment: yes i have changed it, here is my full code: var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId});

//for home page
Meteor.publish("Teams",function(){

    return Groups.find({creator:this.userId},{users:user.services.facebook.id}, {fields:{
        date:false,
        desc:false,
        rules:false,
        friends:false,
        location:false,
        emailAt:false
    }});
});

Comment: the `var user` resolver has to be inside the publish method, so each user has their own instance of a variable when fetching the group list